# PostgreSQL take longest array of one column

Tags: postgresql

I want to use PostgreSQL's functionality in order to obtain the row that has the longest path in either `ind` or `tar` column, **for the same `id`, `ind_id` and `tar_id`.**

For example:

At the table below, since rows 1, 2, 3 have the same `id=1`, `ind_id=2` and `tar_id=3`, I want to only take the 3rd row because the array `tar={7,8,9}`,  is longer than `{7,8}` *(2nd row)* and `{7}` *(1st row)*.

Similarly, rows #4 and #5, have the same values for `id`, `ind_id` and `tar_id`, and since the length of the array in column `ind` is longer in row #5, I want to keep this row only, and drop row #4.

Since I am a newbie in the world of PostgreSQL, can someone give me a hint how to do that?

```python
      text        id       ind_id       tar_id       ind       tar

1     bla bla      1        2             3          {4}       {7}
2     bla bla      1        2             3          {4}       {7,8}
3     bla bla      1        2             3          {4}       {7,8,9}      
4     bla bla      1        2            33          {5}       {10}    
5     bla bla      1        2            33          {5,6,7}   {10}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct on` and `order by id, ind_id, tar_id` and the greatest array length of `ind` and `tar`.

```sql
select distinct on (id, ind_id, tar_id) 
    "text", ind_id, tar_id , ind, tar, pmid
from the_table
order by id, ind_id, tar_id, 
 greatest(array_length(ind, 1), array_length(tar, 1)) desc;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and I get this : `SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function array_length(text, integer) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 241`

Comment: I was thinking that `ind` and `tar` are integer arrays and not text. Pls. see edited answer (with explicit type casts as the error message is hinting). Unrelated but using formatted text instead of array is not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, I tried the updated answer and now I get this: `SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: malformed array literal: "1192"
  Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.`

Comment: Well, then you do have non-array values in `ind` or `tar`. How can you find the array length of a non-array?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Your original answer was correct, I pasted it with a typo, so instead of ind, I used ind_id and I got the first error message. Can you change it back to how it was so that I can accept it?

Comment: Well, it will work fine like this too.

Comment: There is an issue : I get a different view of the table with the `select on (...) *` statement. I was using a `select distinct text, ind_id, tar_id , ind, tar, pmid` to obtain only these columns, but now with the `select distinct on (id, ind_id, tar_id) *`, I have a big number of columns I don't want. How can I fix this in order to get the 6 columns I want?

Comment: Just replace the `*` with a list of columns. Pls. see updated answer.